# get fields in Elastic search response in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am getting below response from elastic search
Can anyone help me in getting only IDs in chain if there are many hits.
eg chainIds = [14,162,123].... if there are 3 hits

```
   "hits" : [
      {
        "_shard" : "******",
        "_node" : "******",
        "_index" : "e******z",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "******",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "chain" : {
            "website" : "234567.com",
            "images" : [
              {
                "url" : ""
              }
            ],
            "name" : "13452e4r5t6y7ui",
            "description" : "<p>23456</p>",
            "id" : 14
          }  
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/search-request-source-filtering.html) to get only the `id` field in the `_source` part

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "chain": {
    "website": "234567.com",
    "images": [
      {
        "url": ""
      }
    ],
    "name": "13452e4r5t6y7ui",
    "description": "<p>23456</p>",
    "id": 123
  }
}
{
  "chain": {
    "website": "234567.com",
    "images": [
      {
        "url": ""
      }
    ],
    "name": "13452e4r5t6y7ui",
    "description": "<p>23456</p>",
    "id": 162
  }
}
{
  "chain": {
    "website": "234567.com",
    "images": [
      {
        "url": ""
      }
    ],
    "name": "13452e4r5t6y7ui",
    "description": "<p>23456</p>",
    "id": 14
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "_source": "chain.id",
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66837269",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "chain": {
            "id": 14
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66837269",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "chain": {
            "id": 162
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66837269",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "chain": {
            "id": 123
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @shaik imran did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: @shaik imran do you have any follow up questions ?